# How do you return lower-cased JSON from a CFCin ColdFusion?

Tags: json, coldfusion, case-sensitive, coldfusion-9

I have a ColdFusion component that will return some JSON data:

```
component
{
    remote function GetPeople() returnformat="json"
    {
        var people = entityLoad("Person");
        return people;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the returned JSON has all the property names in upper case:

```
[
    {
        FIRSTNAME: "John",
        LASTNAME: "Doe"
    },
    {
        FIRSTNAME: "Jane",
        LASTNAME: "Dover
    }
]
```

Is there any way to force the framework to return JSON so that the property names are all lower-case (maybe a custom UDF/CFC that someone else has written)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **From http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_s_03.html**
>   Note: ColdFusion internally represents structure key names using
>   all-uppercase characters, and, therefore, serializes the key names to
>   all-uppercase JSON representations. Any JavaScript that handles JSON
>   representations of ColdFusion structures must use all-uppercase
>   structure key names, such as CITY or STATE. You also use the
>   all-uppercase names COLUMNS and DATA as the keys for the two arrays
>   that represent ColdFusion queries in JSON format.

If you're defining the variables yourself, you can use bracket notation (as Jason's answer shows), but with built-in stuff like ORM I think you're stuck - unless you want to create your own struct, and clone the ORM version manually, lower-casing each of the keys, but that's not really a great solution. :/

Comment: No it is not :(. For one thing, it'll have to be a deep clone, which means all the lazy references will be evaluated.

Comment: If your serializing entities I believe the case transfers exactly as it was written in the cfc: memento = serializeJson(this);

Answer (score 18):

Yeah, unfortunately, that is just the way ColdFusion works. When setting some variables you can force lowercase, like with structs:

```
<cfset structName.varName = "test" />
```

Will set a the variable with uppercase names. But:

```
<cfset structName['varname'] = "test" />
```

Will force the lowercase (or camelcase depending on what you pass in).

But with the ORM stuff you are doing, I don't think you are going to be able to have any control over it. Someone correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you described.

```
component
{
    remote function GetPeople() returnformat="json"
    {
        var people = entityLoad("Person");
        var rtn = [];
        for ( var i = 1; i <= arrayLen( people ); i++ ) {
            arrayAppend( rtn, {
                "firstname" = people[i].getFirstname(),
                "lastname" = people[i].getLastname()
            } );
        }
        return rtn;
    }
}
```

If any of your entity properties return null, the struct key wont exist.
To work around that try this

```
component
{
    remote function GetPeople() returnformat="json"
    {
        var people = entityLoad("Person");
        var rtn = [];
        for ( var i = 1; i <= arrayLen( people ); i++ ) {
            var i_person = {
                "firstname" = people[i].getFirstname(),
                "lastname" = people[i].getLastname()
            };
            if ( !structKeyExists( i_person, "firstname" ) ) {
                i_person["firstname"] = ""; // your default value
            }
            if ( !structKeyExists( i_person, "lastname" ) ) {
                i_person["lastname"] = ""; // your default value
            }
            arrayAppend( rtn, i_person );
        }
        return rtn;
    }
}
```